# Passing a service to an interceptor in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am using Nestjs and want to pass a service to the interceptor with generic types but I am getting errors that Nest cannot resolve the dependencies for the interceptor.

Here is an example:

Here is the interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseInterceptor<Entity, SomeService> implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(public Service: SomeService) {}
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const body: Entity = request.body;
        if(body instanceof CreateProductDto) {
            console.log("product!");
            // do stuff with the service here
        }
        return next.handle().pipe();
    }
}
```

Here is a class extending this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsInterceptor extends BaseInterceptor<CreateProductDto, ProductsService> {
    constructor() {  
      super(new ProductsService());
    }
}
```

And I am calling it on a route:

```
@UseInterceptors(new ProductsInterceptor())
@Post()
....
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to use this interceptor on any route and then define some actions in the interceptor based on the Dto that I receive. I believe the main issue here is how to manage the dependencies for the interceptor within Nest which is what i am not sure about.

Comment: just don't instantiated `ProductsInterceptor` by yourself. Instead, create a factory that will return your `ProductsInterceptor` class (not an instance of it). Pretty much as they do for [`AnyFilesInterceptor`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#any-files). As you can see [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/72a88d5e76d940cf5b7e962d16dcfa999e283a8f/packages/platform-express/multer/interceptors/any-files.interceptor.ts#L19)

Comment: thanks for the note but this doesn't seem to work for me, I am still getting an error that Nest cannot resolve the dependencies for the interceptor

Comment: can you edit your question to show how do you implement that interceptor factory?

Comment: Can you add what error you're getting and what code you're using?